# How to find "x,y" of the line at the intersection of line and viewport edge in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building a graph in Flutter using radial tree view structure. In center I have a core node and it have multiple connecting nodes and sub nodes. The nodes are connected by edge and I am showing the relation label between at the midpoint offset them.

This whole canvas is within an interactive viewer. I can pan and zoom.

Now I want to move the label dynamically on the line based on the visibility of the nodes. If both nodes are visible then I will show label at midpoint. If only one node visible then I want to calculate the midpoint from the visible node offset to the point at which line intersects with the viewport (Dashed line as shown in the image[Radial tree view in the viewport with visible and non visible nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiEcC.png)). I have x1,y1 and x2,y2. I can get the x from the viewport. I want to find the "y".

How can I achieve this?

I have tried the below formula to find y.

```
   y= ((y2-y1)(x-x1)/(x2-x1))+y1
```

But it seems not working for me in this case. I am expecting to move labels dynamically through the line when user pans or zoom the canvas in any direction.

Comment: you cannot do that if you don't know how the line connecting two nodes is made - you could do that if it was a straight line, but as shown in your image it's an unknown curved line